# How to use whisper tflite version on react native for Android

Tags: android, react-native, openai-whisper

I'm currently working on a project that requires the integration of OpenAI Whisper's TFLite (TensorFlow Lite) version into a React Native application. However, I'm facing difficulties finding a suitable module or library to accomplish this task

The react-native-fast-tflite module doesn't support Andtoid. I'm looking for another soultion.
transformer.js version isn't fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can load whisper tflite model in java/kotlin code and run inference. On top of it, you can write react native wrapper.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).